# CONCAT two fields on LEFT JOIN tables

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to CONCAT two fields from left joined tables with query like below?

Below query actually gives me Internal Server Error

```
SELECT job.id as job_id, job.title, job.start_date, job.end_date, organisation.name, jobsboard.name, CONCAT(jobsboard.website, '/?id=', job.id)
            FROM job
            LEFT JOIN portfolio_job_category pjc ON pjc.job_id = job.id
            LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id = pjc.category_id
            LEFT JOIN organisation ON organisation.id = job.organisation_id
            LEFT JOIN portfolio jobsboard ON jobsboard.id = pjc.portfolio_id
            WHERE job.end_date >= DATE( NOW( ) ) 
            AND pjc.portfolio_id = $portfolio
            GROUP BY job.id
            ORDER BY job.id DESC
```

Comment: `Internal Server Error`? Sounds like it's not a problem with your query, if so...

Comment: It's internal server error because it's using PHP to run the query using PDO

Comment: @Jae: Find out what the SQL error message is. Your query looks fine.

Comment: Note that the concat will return NULL if either entry is NULL, so be sure to protect yourself.